# Angular ui-grid Cell validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ui-grid

I want to validate cells in a uigrid with my own validator.
I've found the method setValidator(), but I have no idea how to begin:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.validate.service:uiGridValidateService#methods_setvalidator

In my column definition I have already defined a required validator, but this have no effect:

```
{ name: 'SERIALNO', field: 'SERIALNO', validators: {required: true}, cellTemplate: 'ui-grid/cellTitleValidator', displayName: 'Serialnummer', enableHiding : false, width: 1062  }
```

In my own validator i want to call a webservice, which validates the input.

I have prepared a Plunker to illustrate my problems:

https://plnkr.co/edit/KqQyCqFRr2OwH0CnTP8J?p=info

Thank you for your help!